# Declaring interface on abstract base class

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstract

I am currently implementing the Quartz timer to allow scheduling of some data files. I have a abstract `DataOutput` class and then implementations to cover the different types of output (http, file, etc).  I have implemented the interface on both specialisations but I am having compilation errors when I try and declare this on the abstract base in order to create objects of type DataOutput so I can deal with these at runtime.

Is this possible?

Comment: code and compiler errors may help.

Comment: Yes, can you produce some code?

Comment: Please profide some of the code you are trying to compile (alternately, a lab copy of the simplified problem) and the specific compiler error in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to at least abstractly implement the interface:

```
public interface IExample
{
    string Word { get; set; }
    void DoIt();
}

public abstract class ExampleClass : IExample
{
   public string Word { get; set; }
   public abstract void DoIt();
}
```

*I'm not sure if you've done this since you didn't post any code or errors.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes this was missing (doh :))